# Why can't I use a VBS file to run a BAT file intended to update virus definitions?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, vbscript

The following works in a BAT file.

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" "-SignatureUpdate"
If errorlevel 1 (echo "No Internet connection"
pause > nul
cls
exit)
```

However, when I use the following in a VBS file to run the BAT file, it doesn't work.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "D:\SignatureUpdate.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

I want to use the VBS file to run the BAT file because I don't want to see the Command Prompt window. Can anyone help?

P.S. I can use the VBS file to run the BAT file if the program is `"C:\Windows\write.exe"` but not if it is `"C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe"`.

Comment: Try: WshShell.Run "CMD /C " & chr(34) & "D:\SignatureUpdate.bat" & Chr(34), 0

Comment: (If that works, I'll post it in an answer and can write up an explanation when I'm less tired.)

Comment: `Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run "CMD /C " & chr(34) & "D:\SignatureUpdate.bat" & Chr(34), 0 
Set WshShell = Nothing` It does not work either.

Comment: Dunno.  Looks good to me.  Even tried a simpler version of it.  (Just used a different batch file.)  Worked like a charm.  Dunno why it's not working for you.  Note that if you change the zero to a one, that makes the program easier to notice.

Comment: I have just added a PS into my question.

Comment: While debugging, use `.Run chr(34) & "D:\SignatureUpdate.bat" & Chr(34), 1` with `intWindowStyle` parameter `1` (_Activates and displays a window_) to see what happens. Maybe that `ExecutablePath=C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` and Windows Defender could complain of running in 32-bit environment? Also, `pause` in a hidden `cmd` window causes that the batch never continues (you can't press a key into a hidden window).

Comment: Please post solutions in the form of an actual 'answer' below. Comments may vanish at any time.

Comment: Is there a reason why `pause` can prevent the execution of `MpCmdRun.exe` but not `write.exe`?

Comment: Okay, now that I'm not fighting sleep quite so much, I found that using "CMD /C " is not necessary.  (The theory was that maybe .Run just ran a native executable, and needed the command line interpreter to be able to use a batch file.  However, my test found that .Run did run a batch file fine, without requiring CMD.)  So go ahead and remove the CMD /C

Comment: Regarding pause preventing MpCmdRun but not write, no.  I can think of no reason for that if, as the question's example indicates, you were running pause AFTER running either MpCmdRun or write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Problem solved) Thanks to JosefZ's comment above, I found the following solution, which works perfectly in a BAT file run by the VBS file with no command window.

```
"C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe" "-SignatureUpdate"
If errorlevel 1 ("D:\pop-up message.vbs")
```

Comment: You can (after a brief delay) accept your own answer. This is preferable to adding **Solved** to your question title. (This is not a traditional forum. We do things differently here.)

Comment: I am not allowed to vote for my own post.

Comment: But you can *accept* it (click the green tick mark below the voting arrows). See [help] and [tour] for a brief overview of how the site works.

Comment: The problem wasn't pause.  The problem is that the "pause" command was in a window that was hidden.  Yeah, I did seem to remember saying, "Note that if you change the zero to a one, that makes the program easier to notice."  [MSDN: WshShell .Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/d5fk67ky.aspx).  I'm guessing that you're effectively overriding that by using a .vbs file that sends a new pop-up window into the foreground (even if the batch file window was in the background before).  Note that if that .vbs file uses .Echo, then it will require WScript (not CScript) for that behavior.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake. The fact is that `-SignatureUpdate` could actually be run, but no `echo` could be visible because the window had been hidden by the zero `0` in the VBScript that called the .bat file.